# Python Search Nested Lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

If I have a list of nested lists, what is the easiest way to search for a sublist containing a specific variable at a specific index? For example, if I have a list that looks like the following;

```
mylist = ['aa',1,2,['bb',33],3,['bb',55],56,27,['cc',2],['bb',2,['bb',4]],4,['dd',5,7]]
```

What is the preferred pythonic way of searching this list for lists which have 'bb' in index 0 (first item in a list)? I'm hoping to see the result;

```
['bb',33],['bb',55],['bb',2,['bb',4]],['bb',4]
```

Comment: Is there a limit to how deep the nesting can be?

Comment: What you have tried so far and what's your expected output for your input?

Comment: I don't expect the nesting to go beyond three or four levels but cannot be precise.

Comment: If I search for 'bb'; in index 00, I'm hoping to see the following result - ['bb',33],['bb',55],['bb',2,['bb',4]],['bb',4].

Comment: @JC_RMB what do you mean by "index 00"?

Comment: @ig-melnyk by index 00, I mean the first item in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use a recursive function as such

```
def list_search(slist):
     for count, item in enumerate(slist):
         if(item.__class__ is list):
             list_search(item)
         else:
             if(count == 0 and item == 'bb'):
                 print(slist)
```

This should serve for nesting independent of depth.

Comment: This seems to work very nicely. I had to replace search(item) with list_search(item) but otherwise, it's good to go. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @JC_RMB True, had a little typo there, already fixed it. Glad it solved your problem, let me know if you have any questions on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion works well here, as does using the `__class__` magic member:

```
def recursive_match(the_list):
    index = 0

    for item in the_list:
        print(repr(item))

        if item.__class__ is list:
            recursive_match(item)
        elif index == 0 and item == 'bb':
            print('match')

        index += 1

mylist = ['aa',1,2,['bb',33],3,['bb',55],56,27,['cc',2],['bb',2,['bb',4]],4,['dd',5,7]]
recursive_match(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findList(L, argument, index):
    if L[index] == argument:
        print L
    for element in L:
        if type(element) == list:
            findList(element, argument, index)
```

This might work as well, giving you the ability to choose what argument to search for and the index. But the idea is of course using recursion.